# Closing iPhone SE cover does not lock the phone

Tags: screen-lock, smart-cover

I have an iPhone SE with a [Decoded Case](https://www.decodedbags.com/en/iphone/wallet-case-d6iposewc3bk).

With my Samsung I was used to just close the case and it would automatically lock the screen. How do I turn on this feature on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired feature requires hardware support to be built into the device, which iPhone SE doesn’t have. In fact no iPhone support automatic screen lock with cover based cases.

However the same feature is built into modern iPad(s) (iPad 3 and later) when used with compatible cases.

This feature require presence of magnets in both the device and the case. iPhone doesn’t come with build in magnets.

Also, the website for the case in question nowhere mentions support for this feature.

Comment: Welp, they dropped the ball on this one because it seems like a no-brainer to include this...

Comment: I find pushing the button top right so easy - and it has been the same function since the first iphone so I don’t agree “they dropped the ball”...